# android share app data between the users

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which, in a particular activity there are some articles on which users are supposed to discuss, i.e. post their comments.
So, if anybody comments on a particular article, that comment should be visible to all the users on their cell,who are subscribed to that article.

Now, I am not able to figure out how to carry out this.
I have referred to the developer's site http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/index.html and some SO's questions also but still no ans.

Please help..

Comment: What do you mean by "their cell"?  If you mean other users of other devices within an organization, you will need a server.  If you mean other users of the device, you will have to decide if you mean Android-level user accounts (evolving new feature) or user identities only implemented within your app.

Comment: by their cell, I simply mean, independent users in any part of the world.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store that kind of information in a server somewhere, and access it from the app for each user. Since this is a broad question, it's hard to give you advice specifically on what technologies to use and where to host your server solution. There are many ways you can accomplish this. I would create a web service to store your data about posts and comments in a database of your choice using one of the many web service hosting providers out there:

[Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com)

[Heroku](http://www.heroku.com)

[Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/)

Here's a post I found describing simple backends for a mobile app: [Backends for a mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116843/backend-server-provider-for-mobile-apps)

After reading that, I realized that there are some solutions that you can pay for that will take most of the work out of creating a backend for you. I've heard that Parse is great, but I've never used it myself: [Parse](http://www.parse.com).